# mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given not working

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I try to run this code it shows an error. I am a Newbie to **PHP,MySQL**.The code is as follows:

```
$id=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server.");

$query="Select Code,Name from world.Country limit 10,5";

$query_results=mysqli_query($id,$query);

if($query_results==false)
{

echo"Failed";

}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query_results,MYSQL_BOTH))
{

    $Countrycode= $row['Code'];
    $Countryname= $row['Name'];
    print "$country_name($country_code)<br>\n";`//No display`
}

mysqli_close($id);
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array in mysqli ?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

Interestingly, even though you are not providing a default database to select, your query is still working because you are providng the database identifier in the query itself. So my fisrt suggestion is not the actual problem that you have. Its only the fact that you are using `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array` that you are seeing that error.

**Previous answer**

You have not selected any database to work on. You are missing a call for

```
mysqli_select_db($id,$databaseName);
```

Then you are mixing up `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*`. Read the **[MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)** Manual for proper usage instructions. You can also provide the database name when connecting, like this

```
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database")
```

Then You have to fetch the results using `mysqli`, not `mysql`

[**mysqli_fetch_array**](http://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array)

Comment: I think the error comes from calling `mysql_fetch_array` on a mysqli resource.

Comment: Yep sorry its fixed, I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$databaseName) or die("Could not connect to MySQL server.");
$query="Select Code,Name from world.Country limit 10,5";
$query_results=mysqli_query($id,$query);
if($query_results==false) {
    echo"Failed";
}
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_results,MYSQL_BOTH)){ // You used mysql_fetch_array
    $Countrycode= $row['Code'];
    $Countryname= $row['Name'];
    print "$country_name($country_code)<br>\n";`//No display`
}
mysqli_close($id);
```

if you are using mysqli then you should use mysqli_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the DB name in connection:

```
$id=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DBNAME") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server.");
```

And change mysql_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_array

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query_results)){
......
......
}
```

Comment: Wrong, mysqli_fetch_array expects query in the second parameter, first parameter specifies mysqli resource link. http://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_array